# How to solve trig function

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following function $f(x)$ and known values $a$

$f\left(x\right)=\cos\left(\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x+x^{2}}}\right)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}-x+x^{2}}}\right)\right)\cdot x-a\ \left\{0\ \le\ x\ \le\frac{1}{2}\right\}$

How do I find $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$ for a given value of $a\ \left\{0\ <\ a\ <\ \frac{1}{2}\right\}$

What I am trying to solve;

Given $a$ find the radius $r$ of a circle at point $(0,r)$ such that a line on points $(a, ?)$ to $(\frac{1}{2} ,\frac{1}{2})$ is a tangent of the circle

The tangent line is $y =(x-a)(\frac{1}{2}-\left(b-\sqrt{b^{2}-a^{2}}\right))/(\frac{1}{2}-a)+\left(b-\sqrt{b^{2}-a^{2}}\right)$ for given $a$ when $b$ satisfies $f(b) = 0$

Sorry if I messed up the notation, I have very poor math skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circle of origin $(0,r)$ of radius $|r|$ is given by

$$f(x,y)=x^2+(y-r)^2-r^2=0$$

The straight line passing by $P=(\frac 12,\frac 12)$ and $A=(a,b)$ is given by

$$g(x,y)=(2x-1)(2b-1)-(2y-1)(2a-1)=0$$

First of all if $a=\frac 12$ (vertical line passing by $P$) or $b=\frac 12$ (horizontal line passing by $P$) then the problem can be solved trivially by  two circles of radius $\frac 12$ symmetric to the corresponding axis $(O\vec x)$ or $(O\vec y)$.

So let assume $a,b\neq \frac 12$.

You can for instance solve $g(x,y)=0$ for $y$ and report into $f(x,y)$ to get a quadratic in $x$.

$$x^2+\left(\frac{2xb-x-b+a}{2a-1}-r\right)^2-r^2=0$$

Since the line is a tangent, it means there is only one contact point, therefore the quadratic discriminant should be $0$ which gives a quadratic in $r$ which in turn can be solved to

$$r=\frac{(2-4a)\pm 2\sqrt{4a^2-4a+2+4b^2-4b}}{(4b^2-4b+1)}\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)$$

I let you play with the visual demo:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rw8gee1q6q

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I think my question was very poorly written as I neglected to indicate that the point $(a, ?)$ must be at the tangent point of the circle, $a$ is the only known variable. Should I repost a better version of the question or does your answer have the solution that I just can`t understand? I am a total math nob and will continue to work on your answer if the solution is in there. Demos example of solution I found visually https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fktylyplmq

Comment: I think it probably has simpler solution with the new condition on $a$ so you should post another question. For one, modifying an already posted question a few days after generally attract far less answerers than a new one. Secondly this one might interest someone in the future and he would be glad to find an answer for it. I suggest in the new question that you state the geometric problem first in clear terms, followed by your approach, instead of asking on how to solve $f(x)$ as a starter. You'll get more diversity in the answers this way.